# $S(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{int}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Let $t \in (0, 2\pi)$, calculate $S(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{int}}{n}$.

If we can derive term by term is easy, but how to prove that it is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t \in (0,2\pi)$. The convergence of the serie $S(t)= \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\exp(int)}{n}$ is easily proved with [summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts).

Let $\log : \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the complex logarithm such that $-\log(1-z) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{z^n}{n}$ for $|z|<1$.
Recall a Tauberian theorem.

> **Theorem :** If $\sum a_n z^n$ a serie converging in $\{ |z| < 1 \}$ and if $z_0$ is such that $|z_0|=1$ and $\lim_{N \to +\infty} \sum_{n \leq N} a_n z^n$ converge, then
>   $$\lim_{t \to 1} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n (tz_0)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n z_0^n.$$

This implies that $S(t) = -\log(1-e^{it})$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First use the geometric series

> $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{k-1} =\frac{1}{1-x}, $$

then integrate both sides.

Comment: It seems that the OP is more interested in proving that we can integrate / derive term by term.

Answer (score 0):

The series is equivalent to $-\log(1-e^{it})$.

Comment: Nice Wolfram search.Please,if you know the answer write it down in detail

Comment: @Mitsos Thank you I appreciate that.

Comment: i don't want to be mean.But the OP ask for a way to prove it.